# is it possible to include the value of the 'id' attribute in the 'rendered' condition of a JSF component?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el, rendered-attribute

I need to do something like this, since the rendering depends on the id's value which is also available on my DB:

```
<p:submenu id="id123" rendered="#{mybean.decidedependingof(login.user,component.attributes.get('id'))}">
```

Actually I can obtain the value of the 'id' attribute and use it in the next way for example:

```
<p:submenu id="id123" label="#{component.attributes.get('id')}">
```

which gives me a label with the exact value of the id attribute, but I suppouse that at render time that value is not available yet and the above code is passing a uknown value to the mybean.decidedependingof(..) method.

Any possible solution?
Thanks.

Comment: can you get access to this component.attributes.get('id') from mybean?

Comment: I dont know, but doubt if that would help any way. In the way i'm using it now the component.attributes.get() is called from inside the component <p:submenu> and I interpret the 'component' part in an analogous way as I would interpret the 'this' keyword in Java, so it is relative to 'this' component. I really dont know how to get the same from the bean if that is possible, and how could it help in that case..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: OK I get it now.. I'll try some tests later on